# MYSQL show all rows where no duplicates found

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

If I had a set of data like this:

```
Bob Johnson
James Peters
Bob Johnson
Clare Burns
Peter Pan
Clare Burns
Peter Pan
```

What would be the SQL query to display only "James Peters". So I am not wanting to remove duplicates (DISTINCT command) but rather show all rows where there are no duplicates found.

Comment: That's actually pretty difficult... You'd have to do ORDER BY and then use loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use `group by` for this with a `having` clause:

```
select t.col1, t.col2
from table t
group by t.col1, t.col2
having count(*) = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

the following statement will give you all repeating elements of a given column and how many times they repeat.

```
select col1, count(*) as COUNT
from table
group by 1
having COUNT > 1;
```